# Convert Java list into map where each value in map shares same attribute, using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to convert list into a map such that for some attribute of the list elements, the keys of the map are the element IDs and the values are other element IDs for elements with the same attribute. This is fairly straightforward using a `for` loop, but I'm trying to do it using exclusively Java streams. The main goal is readability, not performance.

Here's how it looks with a for loop - the attribute is the `colorId` in this example:

```
class Apple {
    int _appleId; // different for each apple
    int _colorId; // same for some apples

    Apple(int appleId, int colorId) {
        _appleId = appleId;
        _colorId = colorId;
    }

    int getAppleId() { return _appleId; }
    int getColorId() { return _colorId; }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Apple apple1 = new Apple(1, 7);
    Apple apple2 = new Apple(2, 7);
    Apple apple3 = new Apple(3, 7);
    Apple apple4 = new Apple(4, 8);
    Apple apple5 = new Apple(5, 8);
    Apple apple6 = new Apple(6, 9);

    List<Apple> apples = List.of(apple1, apple2, apple3, apple4,
        apple5, apple6);

    // applesByColor: {7=[1, 2, 3], 8=[4, 5], 9=[6]}
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> applesByColor = apples.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Apple::getColorId,
            Collectors.mapping(Apple::getAppleId, Collectors.toSet())));

    // applesWithSameColor:
    // {1=[1, 2, 3], 2=[1, 2, 3], 3=[1, 2, 3], 4=[4, 5], 5=[4, 5], 6=[6]}
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> applesWithSameColor = new HashMap<>();
    for (var entry : applesByColor.entrySet()) {
        for (var appleId : entry.getValue()) {
            applesWithSameColor
                .computeIfAbsent(appleId, k -> new HashSet<>())
                .addAll(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my ideal results for `applesWithSameColor`:

```
best:   {1=[2, 3], 2=[1, 3], 3=[1, 2], 4=[5], 5=[4]}
better: {1=[2, 3], 2=[1, 3], 3=[1, 2], 4=[5], 5=[4], 6=[]}
good:   {1=[1, 2, 3], 2=[1, 2, 3], 3=[1, 2, 3], 4=[4, 5], 5=[4, 5], 6=[6]}
```

The example shows the `good` output.

What's a nice way to do this using Java streams? It'd be ideal if we could avoid creating the intermediate map `applesByColor` as well.

Comment: Is your question is about performance ? or approach ? what is your problem ?

Comment: @Deadpool The question is about replicating this output using Java streams instead of the double for loop shown in the example.

Comment: Some thing like this `applesByColor.entrySet().stream()
        .forEach(entry -> entry.getValue()
                .stream().forEach(appleId ->
                        applesWithSameColor.computeIfAbsent(appleId, k -> new HashSet<>())
                                .addAll(entry.getValue())
                ));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just stream the values from `applesByColor` Map and then create entries for each value in `Set` and then collect them to `Map`

```
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> applesWithSameColor = applesByColor.values().stream()
            .flatMap(set -> set.stream().map(val -> Map.entry(val, set)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

In case on duplicate key you can also use merge function, to avoid conflicts

```
collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) ->v1)));
```